# How to remove verbose sentences in peer if-else branch

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement

Here I got three if-else branches in this program

```
int main(){
    if(condition == 1)
        functionA();
    if(condition == 2)
        functionB();
    if(condition == 3)
        functionA&B();
    }
```

Suppose that the value of condition only varies from 1 to 3. I wonder if there's way where condition = 3 so that I don't have to call functionA&B() but just use the former result of condition = 1 and condition = 2?

An detailed version of above: 
I got a connection between client and server where client conditionally invokes functions and send the condition value to server, and the server gets the condition value and invokes callback function. For instance, functionA() will send  1, function B() will send 2. The sending can be done as :

```
if((conditionA & 1) > 0)
    functionA();
    send_1();
if((conditionB & 2) > 0）
    functionB();
    send_2();
```

Under this circumstance, the server gets "1" for condA, "2" for condB, "1" and "2" for condC. The server can't judge a full condC request, because 3 is divided by 1 and 2. Therefore, I wanna know whether the sending can be invoked after the 2 if branches and how does server collects the corresponding "1" and "2" to a "3"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Does functionA&B() calls functionA() and functionB()?

Comment: functionA&B() basically combine functionA() with functionB()

Comment: `if (condition % 2) functionA();  if (condition > 1) functionB()` will do it.  This assumes condition can only have the values 1-3, and that the intent is to call `functionB()` after `functionA()`.

Comment: Can `functionA`/`functionB` change `condition` ?

Comment: no, condition here is just for branches @Jarod42

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use bit-wise AND:

```
if ((condition & 1) > 0) // true when condition is 1 or 3
    functionA();
if ((condition & 2) > 0) // true when condition is 2 or 3
    functionB();
```

Comment: In c++ you need to enclose `(condition & 1)` in parentheses

Comment: @metalfox oops, in Java too. Thanks for the correction

Comment: BTW `!=` might be better than `>` if you ever test the top bit.

Comment: If the 1 and 2 is enum type, is it correct to use & ?

Comment: @asapdiablo you can't apply bit-wise operators on enums.

Answer (score 2):

If is doesn't matter that you do B first

```
if (condition >= 2) {
    functionB();
    condition = condition - 2;
}

if (condition == 1) {
    functionA();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( condition != 2 ) functionA() ;
if( condition > 1 ) functionB() ;
```

Or turn `condition` into a bitmask. It's been a while since I've done this in C and I'm on mobile so please forgive any silly mistakes in the first cut; I'll come back to edit it later.

```
#define CREEPY 1
#define MYSTERIOUS 2
#define SPOOKY 4
// continue with powers of 2 to extend

if( condition & ( CREEPY | SPOOKY ) )
    functionA() ;
if( condition & ( MYSTERIOUS | SPOOKY ) )
    functionB() ;
```

This has the advantages of being self-documenting, avoiding magic numbers, and being a bit more adjustable if you change your mind about what the conditions are.

If the sole meaning of `condition` of `3` is "both 1 and 2", you can even (coincidentally) get away with not changing the numeric values, because `3=1|2`.

```
#define CREEPY 1
#define KOOKY 2

// set 3 as:
// condition = CREEPY | KOOKY ;

if( condition & CREEPY ) functionA() ;
if( condition & KOOKY ) functionB() ;
```

Comment: thank you, marco seems to give me a better way to solve this since 3 here does mean do both 1 and 2@zerobandwidth